# Sort by 2nd field

Tags: bash, sorting

Here's a sample of what I have in a log file:

```
p1-OST001e oss031
p1-OST001f oss032
p1-OST0020 oss033
p1-OST0021 oss034 
p1-OST0022 oss035
p1-OST0023 oss036
p1-OST0024 oss037
p1-OST0025 oss038
p1-OST0026 oss039
p1-OST0027 oss040
p1-OST0028 oss031
```

I want to sort it so the 2 OSTs match up with the oss ie.

```
p1-OST001e oss031
p1-OST0028 oss031
p1-OST001f oss032
etc
```

would be together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$ sort -t' ' -nk2.4 file
p1-OST001e oss031
p1-OST0028 oss031
p1-OST001f oss032
p1-OST0020 oss033
p1-OST0021 oss034 
p1-OST0022 oss035
p1-OST0023 oss036
p1-OST0024 oss037
p1-OST0025 oss038
p1-OST0026 oss039
p1-OST0027 oss040
```

- `-t' '` sets space as field separator
- `-n` sets numeric sort
- `-k2.4` sets column 2 to be the index to sort by. With `.4` we indicate to sort from the 4th character.